# How do I establish a connection between 2 computers on different subnetworks?

Tags: port-forwarding, tcp, udp, subnet

computer A(192.168.1.134) needs to establish a UDP connection to computer C(192.168.0.30).

As you can see both are on a different subnetwork.  Now I have computer B which has 2 IP addresses, one for each subnetwork (192.168.1.135 and 192.168.0.37).  A can ping B and B can C but A cant ping C.  How can I use computer B to establish the connection between A and B.  Remember that computer A needs to connect with a program I made so I cant do any command line stuff.   Would port forwarding work?  How would I do this?

Im thinking of doing SSH -L 10002:192.168.0.30:10002 192.168.1.135 but then even if this works will I still have create another forwarding so that communication will go both ways?

Comment: There's probably a mistake in your question, since both computers A and C are on network 192.168.1.0/24

Comment: your right my bad that was a typo

Comment: Which O/S are A/B/C?

Comment: A= windows B=Ubuntu C= no OS its an embedded device without any OS

Comment: Each machine, or its default router, must know to use the gateway to reach machines on the other subnet.

Answer (score 2):

i think you just have to enable packet forwarding on computer B. For example on Ubuntu that is done by running:

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```

Now the computer can take packets received on one interface and send them out on another interface.

Edit: On Ubuntu that doesn't work with sudo, I had to use "sudo su" and then run the above as root.

Comment: thx i'll give it as try

Comment: there is only one interface though

Comment: can you post the outputs of "ifconfig" and "route", please?

Comment: Check A's "route" as well. Does it have a route (host, network or default) for a packet bound for C (192.168.0.30)? And does C by default forward everything to B?