# How to Browse Machine on Sub-Network

Tags: windows-explorer, subnet

How can I browse a machine on a sub-network?

Our primary network addresses are at `192.168.1.x`

In our LAN we also have a little wireless Netgear router with some devices connected to it, which assigns DCHP to it's own `10.0.0.x` network.

Now, I want to use my windows computer to browse the files on a machine in the subnetwork.  I'm not connecting two subnets - I want to browse a subnet from the parent network.

I am admin on the Netgear, so I can change the settings.  I read [here](https://superuser.com/questions/86987/how-do-i-establish-a-connection-between-2-computers-on-different-subnetworks) and [here](https://superuser.com/questions/542234/access-webserver-in-a-subnetwork) about port forwarding, but I'm afraid to change anything unless I understand what I am doing.  This [thread looks](https://superuser.com/questions/104774/access-machine-in-a-subnetwork-after-a-router) like it is trying something similar, but I don't see how to apply any solution.

Is there a way I can map it from my Windows workstation?  Or is this something I need to adjust in the router?

I'd like to type in the device name into Windows Explorer, such as \mydevice and browse that way.  I can do this on a machine that is on the subnet, but not from a machine on the parent network.

Comment: Unless the Netgear router is assigned its own 192.168.1.x address what and assigns devices connected to it 10.0.0.x address what you want is simply not possible.  You shouldn't have to port forward anything if all your talking about is windows explorer.

Comment: The netgear does have it's own 192.168.1.x address, but it assigns 10.0.0.x addresses to its subnet.

Comment: Can I create a port on the router's 192.168.1.x address that forwards to my machine's 10.0.0.x address?  Like: \\192.198.1.2:1111 ?

Comment: What is the gateway on the computer?  **ipconfig /all**

Comment: The gateway is 10.0.0.1.

Answer (score 1):

Should be pretty straightforward.  I'm making the assumption that you've got the Netgear connected via it's "WAN" interface to your main 192.168.1.x subnet.

First, you need to define a route that tells your machines how to get to the 10.0.0.x subnet.  You can do this either on the workstation or in the router for your 192.168.1.x subnet.  The route will specify the Netgear's 192.168.1.x IP as the gateway to use for the 10.0.0.x network.

As an example, to do this at your workstation, you would enter the following (correcting the entries for your environment):

> route -p ADD DESTINATION-SUBNET MASK DESTINATION-SUBNETMASK IP-OF-NETGEAR

Example:

> route -p ADD 10.0.0.0 MASK 255.0.0.0 192.168.1.2

Then in the Netgear, set your firewall rules to allow incoming traffic on the WAN link (the 192.168.1.x interface) FROM the 192.168.1.x network.  There are sometimes multiple settings you need to watch for, as the default for most firewalls is to block traffic from private subnets when they're seen on a WAN interface.  Also be sure to have rules to allow traffic back out to the 192.168.1.x subnet (usually enabled by default).

For the last piece, edit your local hosts file on the workstation to assign a machine name to the IP, for example:

> 10.0.0.2 myserver

With these settings, when you access "myserver", your computer looks for the 10.0.0.2 IP.  It sees in the routing tables that it needs to talk to the Netgear's 192.168.1.x IP for this.  The Netgear's config allows the traffic and routes your data to the 10.0.0.x subnet.

Comment: I don't have access to the parent network's router (long story), so I went with configuring the route on my workstation (192.168.1.xxx).  When I type in your example, I get `bad argument 192.168.1.2` even though I KNOW that is the ip address for the Netgear router (I have the web interface open to it).  I'm sorry to be so bone-headed here...

Comment: I know you are going to ask if I can ping 192.168.1.2 and yes, I can.

Comment: @BGM Syntax needed correction, I updated post with this.

Comment: That new syntax took!  Okay, now I'm trying to get the browsing part.

Comment: I'm not sure where to look for the wan setting.  I don't see where to create rules for traffic.  I have a Netgear Genie.  Do I look under "static routes" or "port forwarding"?

Comment: You shouldn't need to create any routes on the Netgear.  You will need to create or define firewall rules to allow traffic through the firewall. Maybe you can disable it completely?  I'm not familiar with Netgear Genie, sorry.

Comment: @BGM Some online doc suggested this: Add a new rule for Inbound Services with a service name of “ANY” and an action of “ALLOW always.” Then, move the new rule up until it is the first rule in the Inbound Services section. Finally, make certain that this rule is enabled by checking the Enable column.

Comment: I think there are no firewall rules enabled (no reason, anyway, inside the LAN).  Now, I should be able to browse to \\10.0.0.2 (my machine's address on that subnet), right?

Comment: Consumer grade routers have a firewall enabled on the WAN interface by default, as this is the link that is intended to be connected to the Internet.  The router has no way to "detect" your configuration and see that the WAN link in your instance is connected to a private LAN.  You will have to add a firewall rule to allow access.

Comment: I can't even find the word firewall anywhere in the configuration.  The only place I can see that let's me create rules is in "static routes" or "port forwarding".  I've scoured the interface.

Comment: @BGM It's possible it doesn't let you configure the firewall; some simple, consumer grade routers just don't have that functionality. You could look into replacing the firmware with a solution like DD-WRT or tomato to get more advanced options.  Sorry I don't have more specific advice RE: Netgear Genie configuration.  Another option would be to contact NetGear support to see how to configure your router.

Comment: Okay, well, you've been quite helpful.  I'll play around some more, and I'll mark the thread solved when I figure it out.  Thanks for your attention.